# jenkins multiple console output

Tags: batch-file, selenium, jenkins

I'm fairly new to jenkins. I'm trying to execute two .bat files(or directly two commands) from jenkin, the first one will startup selenium and the second will execute a test file (with protractor). 
The problem is that when selenium is started, I no longer have hand to input more commands in the console.
I tried `start cmd \k` to get to another console, and `CALL`s for two different .bat file, but the console keeps showing the output the trace of selenium being executed.

How can I jump from the bloking console executing selenium to another console to execute my tests (while selenium is still being executed) ?

Comment: Why are you starting selenium via jenkins? If that's what you want you should probably look into using this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

Comment: I want my job to start selenium, execute the test (generate the reports ) and stop selenium. My tests are on my local computer for now

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to start your webdriver?

Comment: `cd \path\to\repo`
`webdriver-manager start`

Comment: And since my I didn't install protractor globally, I then have:
`cd \path\to\protractor` `protractor \path\to\tests\testConf.js`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
start powershell ".\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

Replacing the .exe file name with your executable.